# how to know how many victories need to qualify

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm participating in a soccer tournament, and I'm on a group with 7 teams, in this group will be qualify 4 teams, and 3 teams will be eliminated.

How to know how many victories need to qualify my team to the next stage?

**EDIT:**
Is only one game for each pair of teams.

- One victory gain 3 points.
- Draw each team  win 1 point.
- Loser don't win nothing points.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: It's possible for all teams to have three victories and three losses, thereby going into tie-breakers which does _not_ guarantee that you qualify. So you'd need at least three wins and a draw. I don't know if that's enough.

Comment: Its not a homework, is a true story haha, I don't know how to proceed :(

Comment: Thanks Arthur. Its what I need.

Comment: How many games between each pair of teams?

Comment: Is only one game for each pair of teams.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at points rather than victories.

You could have four teams all drawing with each other and all losing to the remaining three teams.  Then (assuming there is a tie-breaker) one team will qualify with $3$ points and no wins.

Or you could have five teams each winning two of their four matches among each other *(Ab Ac Bc Bd Cd Ce Da De Ea Eb)* and each both their two matches against the other teams.  Then (assuming there is a tie-breaker) one team will be eliminated with $12$ points and four wins.

So $13$ points or more guarantee qualification and $2$ or fewer guarantee elimination, but without further information $3-12$ points give an uncertain outcome.

In answer to your original question "how many victories need to qualify my team to the next stage?" the answer is that $5$ or more wins guarantee qualification but $0-4$ wins neither guarantee qualification nor guarantee elimination.